# Jekyll common page, post config

Tags: jekyll

I can't find this solution anywhere, i don't know if it's possible but is there any chance to set common Jekyll post config, at least some part of it.

I've tried couple of ways...

**by include** as a markdown and html

post_config.md

```
---
layout: blog
bodyClass: blog
excerpt_separator: <!--more-->
permalink: blog/:categories/:year/:month/:day/:title.html
```

02-08-1016-post.md

```
{% include post_config.md %}
title: Hello.
author: Some Dude.
---
```

**by defaults** from main config

```
#Defaults
defaults:
  scope:
    path: '_posts'
    type: 'pages'
  values:
    layout: blog
    bodyClass: blog
    excerpt_separator: <!--more-->
    permalink: blog/:categories/:year/:month/:day/:title.html
```

**by inheritace** from main template

Nothing works...  Is it doable? Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the **Front Matter defaults** section of the [Jekyll Configuration guide](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/).

Specifically, you can define a `defaults` key in your `_config.yml` file that lists default values for every file. You can narrow the scope and specify default values for particular types of posts.

Here's an example:

> ```
> defaults:
>   -
>     scope:
>       path: ""
>       type: "posts"
>     values:
>       layout: "my-site"
>   -
>     scope:
>       path: "projects"
>       type: "pages" # previously `page` in Jekyll 2.2.
>     values:
>       layout: "project" # overrides previous default layout
>       author: "Mr. Hyde"
> ```
>
> With these defaults, all posts would use the `my-site` layout. Any
>   html files that exist in the `projects/` folder will use the `project`
>   layout, if it exists. Those files will also have the `page.author`
>   liquid variable set to `Mr. Hyde.`

Try that out, and if you still can't get it working, please try to be more specific than saying "nothing works". Try to be more specific about exactly what you're doing, exactly what you expect to happen, and exactly what happens instead. Good luck.

Comment: Hey dude, you've copied the docs from official page... and if you look more precisely i've wrote that the defaults not works to.

Comment: @Lukas I linked to the official page, and indicated that the example is a quote. I'm not trying to pass this off as anything other than a copy of what's in the official configuration guide. But like I said, if this isn't working, you're going to have to be much more specific than saying it doesn't work. What **exactly** are you doing? What exactly do you expect to happen? What exactly happens instead?

Comment: I need to keep some part of page/post configuration common with rest ones, like layout name, body class, maybe more in the feature. So, to avoid adding new config notation for each post i need to delegate some kind of common config that can be included as a part of several posts config.

Comment: @Lukas That's exactly what the `defaults` key does. Please post exactly what you've tried, and exactly what happened when you tried it.

Comment: You can find in above. There is one file - post_config.md when the config begins with `---` notation and as a partial is included to the post, in post we have the rest of config and it closer `---` then i have rendered plain text with config. And when i'm using the defaults, there is no react, i have naked post without appended layout. I'm gonna add my defaults config right now.

Comment: @Lukas You're going to need the `---` notation (the front matter) for the post to be recognized by Jekyll. And why is your `path` set to `_posts`? What are you trying to do there? If you want it to apply to everything, then just use empty quotation marks.